# Is PiGlow compatible with model B+, and will both fit inside a Pibow?

Tags: hardware, pi-models

So, can I use [PiGlow](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/piglow/) with Raspberry Pi B+?

If yes, does it fit inside a [Pibow enclosure](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/pibow/)?

Comment: Probably not since the new 40 pin gpio will block the female headers from the PiGlow. Assuming you somehow manage to get the header to fit (some have suggested cutting off the offending pins - not something I would suggest), it appears that it will fit inside a PiBow case designed for the model B+ (A PiBow case for the model B will not work because of the new layout of the board).  Having said that this might better be asked of the manufacturer or reseller of the board, as they are the only ones who are likely to be able to provide a definitive answer at this point.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows a lack of pre-asking research. While OP may have had good intentions, it still needs to be removed as basic googling can find this out.

Comment: I could not find that when I asked. Now it is easy to find it from google.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness - Not sure if simply googling will answer the second question, though. It may require someone who has purchased both of said products to see if they fit, when used in conjunction. Or, as Steve suggests, the manufacturer may need contacting. I have done just that, and I am awaiting a definitive reply. I will post the answer.

Comment: @Greenonline No, you're right, it probably doesn't However, that's still asking two questions in one, something that goes against the best practices for asking questions on Stack Exchange (one question per post.)

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness - True, but they _were_ only little questions ;-)  I got an answer btw, see below, but basically - yes and yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PiGlow DOES work with B+ as shown in [this review video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VMimap3TIs)

As for what scripts work currently for it that worked on the B model is yet to be determined. I just tried using [Boeeerb's script](https://github.com/Boeeerb/PiGlow) hoping to run the binary clock at start up like I once tried on the B model and I keep getting an error message stating 
"Unable to determine Raspberry Pi revision" Also note that the last update made to this Git repo was 3 months ago.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know definitely, but based upon [this evidence](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=93&t=82347), the fact that this person is shipping a PiGlow with a B+ probably means that it is compatible. Now, as I said, I don't know this for sure.

Comment: They're selling both a B and a B+ in that bundle... I think the PiGlow probably "goes with" the B, here.

Comment: @Tripp Lilley Oh yeah, didn't notice that...

Answer (score 1):

I have a definitive answer from the manufacturer.

I asked:

> I was wondering if the PiGlow is compatible with the Pi B+ and RPi 2?
>   Also, would a PI fitted with a PiGlow both fit inside a Pibow? I am
>   interested in purchasing both items, IF they fit together.

The answer:

> The PiGlow is compatible with the RPi 2 and B+ and it will fit inside
>   a Pibow :-)